# Solved - EF Relationship Child has many parent and Parent has many children

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Building a dynamic form where Entities and its fields can be created by the user. The possible dataTypeId from EntityField can be EntityId so that look up can be an Entity.

```
   public class Entity : Base, IBase
   {
    public Entity()
    {
        EntityFields = new HashSet<EntityField>();
        PickFromEntity = new HashSet<EntityField>();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Remote("CheckDuplicate", "Entity", HttpMethod = "POST")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EntityField> EntityFields { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EntityField> PickFromEntity { get; set; }
}


 public class EntityField : Base, IBase
{
    public EntityField()
    {
        EntityChildren = new HashSet<Entity>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid EntityId { get; set; }      //Field for What Entity

    [StringLength(255)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string HelpDescription { get; set; }
    public short Order { get; set; }
    public Guid DataTypeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<Guid> PickListId { get; set; }      //if DAtatype is Picklist 
    public Nullable<Guid> PickFromEntityId { get; set; } //if DAtatype is Entity
    public Nullable<int> Minimum { get; set; }      //Will ast as Total rows for Data Type Table
    public Nullable<int> Maximum { get; set; }      //Will ast as Total Columns for Data Type Table
    public bool IsVisibleOnSelect { get; set; } = false;   //Only for Entity Data Type
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; } = false;

    public string Format { get; set; }
    public string DefaultValue { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PickFromEntityId")]
    public virtual Entity PickFromEntity { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PickListId")]
    public virtual PickList PickList { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EntityId")]
    public virtual Entity Entity { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DataTypeId")]
    public virtual ListOfValue DataType { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Entity> EntityChildren { get; set; }
}
```

The Migration throws an error :
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Entity.PickFromEntity' of type 'ICollection'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: Your collections need `[ForeignKey(...)]` attributes, since you have more than one relationship between these tables.

Comment: Adding Collection with a foreign Key does not solves it. May be in am putting it wrong can you help with the code.

Comment: `code` builder.Entity<EntityField>(entity =>
            {
                entity
                    .HasOne(e => e.PickFromEntity)
                    .WithMany(p => p.EntityDataType)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.PickFromEntityId);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.PickFromEntity)
                .WithMany(p => p.EntityDataType)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.EntityId);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Entity)
                    .WithMany(d => d.EntityFields)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.EntityId);
            }); `code`

Comment: Fluent API? Don't try to paste that much code into a comment, update the question. Just make sure you haven't missed any of your FK's.